# C Is it possible for a function taking va_list to use it more than once?

Tags: c, variadic-functions

In the program below, the variadic function `process_message` passes its variable arguments via the `va_list argp` parameter to `print_message`. `argp` is in turn passed to `vsnprintf` which calculates the length of the format string.

However, if `argp` is passed to a another function called from within `print_message` such as `vprintf(fmt, argp)`, it produces nonsense output. Is it possible for a function taking `va_list` parameter to use it more than once?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void process_message(const char *fmt, ...);
void print_message(const char *fmt, va_list argp);

int main(void) {
  process_message("%s:%d\n", "test message", 1);
  return 0;
}

void process_message(const char *fmt, ...) {
  va_list argp;
  va_start(argp, fmt);
  print_message(fmt, argp);
  va_end(argp);
}

void print_message(const char *fmt, va_list argp) {
  /*Calculate and print the length of the format string*/
  int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, argp);
  printf("Length of format string = %d\n", len);
  /*Print the rendered format string - this produces a nonsense output
   *if argp was aleady passed to another function earlier */
  vprintf(fmt, argp);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`va_copy`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/va_copy):

> The va_copy() macro copies the (previously initialized) variable argument list src to dest. The behavior is as if va_start() were applied to dest with the same last argument, followed by the same number of va_arg() invocations that was used to reach the current state of src.

You `print_message()` could be:

```
void print_message(const char *fmt, va_list argp) {
  /*Calculate and print the length of the format string*/ 
  va_list argp_copy;
  va_copy(argp_copy, argp);
  int len = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, fmt, argp_copy);
  va_end(argp_copy);

  printf("Length of format string = %d\n", len);
  /*Print the rendered format string - this produces a nonsense output
   *if argp was aleady passed to another function earlier */
  vprintf(fmt, argp);
}
```

**NOTE:**

Don't forget to call `va_end` after using a copied `va_list`.

[C11](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16.1):

> Each invocation of the va_start and va_copy macros shall be matched by a corresponding invocation of the va_end macro in the same function.